# Unable to deploy web application using Tomcat 7.077 and IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.2

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat7

[image]I do not get any errors as such while deploying my application to tomcat.I have redirected the same to a browser however it does not seem to open the browser at all.
I have tried clearing history .Create my tomcat instance again and also killed processes running on the ports. This was working for months and suddenly not working.

[2017-04-28 04:13:38,882] Artifact xxxx:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2017-04-28 04:13:38,882] Artifact xxxx:war exploded: Deploy took 12,093 milliseconds

Comment: Check Tomcat logs for errors, also check `lsof` output to verify that Tomcat indeed listens on this port.

Comment: there are no errors.and i tried lsof it says port is closed. I also tried starting tomcat without a war. So it opens the browser with http but not with https.

Comment: Try a clean Tomcat installation and make sure to enable HTTPS via `server.xml`.

Comment: I already did that. Still does not seem to work. I am able to deploy the application on http port but not on https port,which was working fine until recently